# How can I simplify an equation in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

I am new to LaTeX, and I am using OverLeaf. I am trying to typeset simplifying  the equation `u+v-w=p*r+q*s-(q-p)*(s-r)=p*s+q*r`.

I tried:

```
\begin{align} 
  \left\ u+w-v &= p\times r + q\times s - (q-p)\times (s-r) \\ & = p\times s +q\times r 
\end{align}
```

Comment: I want to deal with the typesetting.... that is why i wrote what the equation simplifies too. I need help typesetting it in LaTex so that everything aligns nicely.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: \begin{align}
\left\ u+w-v &= p\times r + q\times s - (q-p)\times (s-r) \\
& = p\times s +q\times r  

\end{align}

Comment: I just need help typesetting a string of equalities so that its algined

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add a minimal but complete document showing the code you have tried? The snippet you pasted in the comments doesn't compile (the `\left\ ` part needs to be removed). As your question stands, it's not clear what parts exactly you need help on.

Comment: in your code snippet is `\left\ `, which is not defined. `latex` interpret it as `\left` and `\  ` (empty space) so it complain that there is missing delimiter ... just remove it and your example will compile without warning and givs result which you like to obtain.

Answer (score 3):

A full MWE for those using a TeX editor would look like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} % required for align
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    u + w - v &= p \times r + q \times s - (q-p) \times (s-r) \\
    &= p \times s + q \times r
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

I think I figured it out. This is what I was trying to do.

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers if you replace the screen shot of your code with the actual code (like you did in your question).